# Fabric retries thrice on receiving nonzero return code

Tags: python, flask, fabric

I am trying to ssh in to a server, edit a few files and shutdown a tomcat server using Fabric. 
I have observed that if my server shutdown fails with an exception, fabric retries the whole process again. I have looked at the Fabric docs and there seems to be no way to disable this behavior. I would like to disable these retries that Fabric does.

Any suggestions?

#### UPDATE:

What I am doing is this:

```
with settings(host_string='user@host'):  
    run('sg group -c /home/me/tomcat/bin/stop.sh')
```

If this shutdown fails because of, say, tomcat is not already up, then fabric receives a non zero exit code and retries thrice before exiting.

**Note:
This is happening when I call this part via. a Flask view. When run standalone, it works just fine.**

===================================================

#### UPDATE:

Debugged more to find this had nothing to do with Fabric. It was happening due to Flask re-calling the Fabric code when it encountered a non-zero return code (uncaught exception) from fabric.

Solved this by adding a check for return codes on each fabric run() call and then raising an exception manually in Flask space.

Comment: could you provide a [minimal complete code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows that Fabric retries on non-zero return code by default (or show where it is said in the docs)? You could use `false` program as an example.

Comment: How are you invokin your fabric tack?

Comment: Hi @pbacterio , I am calling this fabric task from a Flask view. Basically it is called from a web app, using the code I've put above. I am puzzled as to why it retries from a Flask app while if I run it stand alone, it does not retry.